# How to sub navigation bar css?

Tags: html, css

I want to make sub menu under the `Accounts` button. I want the sub menu to show when I hover over `Accounts` button.  I tried this but it doesn't work:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> Ahmed Shihab | Me </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="about.css" >
        <link href="https://allfont.net/allfont.css?fonts=courier" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Arvo&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="topnav">
        <a href="main.html">Home  </a>
        <a href="about">About  </a>
        <a class="acc" href="acc">Accounts</a>   <!-- THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO MAKE IT BUTTON --> 
        <a class="hide" href="face">-Facebook </a>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So I want to change `Account` to a button that when it is hovered over, it shows me the `Facebook` link, and I want to add a `Twitter` link downside the `Facebook`.

**CSS:**

```
.acc {
    font-family:'Courier', arial;
    color:black;
    font-size:3em;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    overflow:hidden;;
}
.hide {
    font-family:"Courier";
    color:black;
    font-size:3em;
    display:hidden;
    position:relative; top:45px; right:234px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what do you want to achieve?

```css
.subnav{
    display: none;
}

.topnav li:hover .subnav{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> Ahmed Shihab | Me </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="about.css" >
        <link href="https://allfont.net/allfont.css?fonts=courier" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Arvo&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
    <ul class="topnav">
        <li><a href="main.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about">About</a>
            <ul class="subnav">
                <li class="acc"><a href="acc">Accounts</a></li>   <!-- THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO MAKE IT BUTTON --> 
                <li class="hide"><a href="face">-Facebook</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would highly recommend you to learn something about CSS selectors and especially about [:hover](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp).

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and I will learn more about it